# Data not being inserted mysql

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

I am building a custom CMS for myself and its going great but for some reason the system is not inserting a certain field called categories. I have a table called categories and i am able to insert those categories with no problems.
On my addnewpost.php page I have this form field that lets me select an added Category..

```
<select name="Category" id="categorytitle" class="form-control">
 <?php 
   $sql = "SELECT id,title FROM category";
   $stmt = $conn->query($sql);
   while ($DataRows = $stmt->fetch()){
     $id = $DataRows["id"];
     $CategoryName = $DataRows["title"];
 ?>
   <option value=""><?php echo $CategoryName; ?></option>
 <?php } ?>
</select>
```

above all that I have this to inset the data into the database in a table called posts...

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["Submit"])){
  $posttitle  = $_POST["posttitle"];
  $Category   = $_POST["Category"];
  $image      = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
  $target     = "../uploads/".basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
  $posttext   = $_POST["postdescription"];
  $admin      = "phillip";

  date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
  $CurrentTime=time();
  $DateTime=strftime("%B-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S",$CurrentTime);

  if(empty($posttitle)){
    $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = "Post title cannot be empty";
    redirect_to("addnewpost.php");
  } elseif (strlen($posttitle)<10){
    $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = "Post title should be greater than 10 characters";
    redirect_to("addnewpost.php");
  } else {
    //All is good insert into the database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO posts(datetime,title,category,author,image,post)";
    $sql .= "VALUES(:dateTime,:postTitle,:categoryName,:adminName,:imageName,:postDescription)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':dateTime',$DateTime);
    $stmt->bindValue(':postTitle',$posttitle);
    $stmt->bindValue(':categoryName',$Category);
    $stmt->bindValue(':adminName',$admin);
    $stmt->bindValue(':imageName',$image);
    $stmt->bindValue(':postDescription',$posttext);

    $Execute=$stmt->execute();
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],$target);

    if($Execute){
      $_SESSION["SuccessMessage"]="Post with id : ".$conn->lastInsertId()." Added Successfully";
      redirect_to("addnewpost.php");
    } else {
      $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"]="Something went wrong. Try again";
      redirect_to("addnewpost.php");
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Here is a screengrab showing that the category fields are empty. I do have display errors enabled but none are showing up. Any thoughts appreciated...

[image]

Comment: `<option value="">` shouldn't be `<option value="$id">`?

Comment: More likely `<option value="<?php echo $id; ?>">`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Nigel and Felippe. I just took out the option value so it's just this instead...

```
<option><?php echo $CategoryName; ?></option>
```

That's made it all work perfectly. Been looking at this for hours as well.
Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <select name="Category" id="categorytitle" class="form-control">
     <?php 
       $sql = "SELECT id,title FROM category";
       $stmt = $conn->query($sql);
       while ($DataRows = $stmt->fetch()){
         $id = $DataRows["id"];
         $CategoryName = $DataRows["title"];
     ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $CategoryName; ?>"><?php echo $CategoryName; ?></option>
     <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

This is more like it